# How can I be completely sure a question hasn't been asked before?

Tags: discussion, questions

I was looking for an answer to this question: How to completely remove a namespace using DOMDocument [php] but I didn't find one, although I did find similar answers that use different libraries. I have since worked out the answer by myself with a bit of research and a bit of trial and error. I want to create one of those self-answered questions but I don't want someone to say 15 minutes later "duplicate of X".

How can I be really sure that it hasn't been answered before or should I just post it anyway?

Comment: What's wrong with questions marked as duplicate?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Because SO just becomes Google!

Comment: The purpose of duplicates at SO is to setup a network of frequently asked questions, such these can be easier found by anyone. So you'll get your answer, and a future researcher may easier find it because of a broader variety of search keys available.

Comment: I've found that with duplicate questions (a lot of them without accepted answers) I have to search through a lot of them to find the right answer. Having the best answer in one place helps me. Also, some questions almost instantly get closed as duplicates, adding no value to the site.

Comment: I think the biggest problem of SO is that people misinterpret the mechanisms in place to keep the machine running smoothly. Duplicates ARE a value to the site and its users, regardless of your opinion on that matter. You say that duplicates which are instantly closed are useless; not in my eyes. It creates an up-to-date link to a possible old question and solution, indicating it is still relevant today.

Comment: There's actually no way to be _completely_ sure your question isn't a duplicate because sometimes the question title doesn't really match the question itself. The best you can do is see whether a duplicate is likely to be found.

Comment: I found this question sincere, and helpful

Answer (score 4):

Try to phrase your question in a few different ways and search for all of those.

Just do keyword searches (e.g. "php remove namespace domdocument") in addition to searching for actual questions (e.g. "how do i remove namespace in domdocument with php").

Search using Google rather than, or in addition to, directly on Stack Overflow. Google is a search engine, focussing exclusively on search, while search on Stack Overflow is more of an extension, so you'd expect the prior to be better. On the other hand, being able to search using tags, answers, score, date and other properties makes Stack Overflow search very powerful, so it shouldn't be ignored.

---

My rule of thumb to see whether someone did any amount of searching before asking (which tends to effect whether or not I downvote, although not so much with self-answered questions) is to type the title as is (perhaps adding a language keyword) into Google and see if I can get an answer (not from the question I'm checking). I'd recommend doing that specifically.

---

If you've searched a bit and didn't find anything, don't be too concerned with your question being marked as a duplicate - it can always serve as a pointer to the duplicate for someone trying to search in the same way you did.

Comment: I guess the difference is because I'm going to answer the question myself. I already have the answer and I want to share it with the community (and myself in future if I forget how to do it!)

Comment: @CJDennis as long as both question and answer meet the same standards we'd apply to content from two separate people, there is no difference.